# IntelliJ IDEA equivalent of Edit.GoToNext/PrevLocation

Tags: intellij-idea

In Visual Studio 2019 I can use Find in Files to find some text in my code.  Then I can use Edit.GoToNextLocation and Edit.GoToPrevLocation to move through the matches.  (I have them mapped to Ctrl-N and Ctrl-Shift-N.)  This allows me to jump from location to location and edit as necessary without having to use the mouse.

How can I do the same thing in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it!

IntelliJ IDEA appears to have a **Next Occurrence** command that does what I want.

It seems that to get a navigable list of found results, I need to do **Find in Path...** followed by **Open in Find Window** (Ctrl-Enter).  Then **Next Occurrence** and **Previous Occurrence** (not to be confused with Move to Next Occurrence and Move to Previous Occurrence!) take me through the various places.

In IntelliJ IDEA it doesn't loop back to the first result like Visual Studio does, but I can live with that.

I do wish it would go straight to the Find Window instead of me having to tell it to.

Comment: Good finding, yeah!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, I suggest you get familiar with "Action" shortcut (control+shift+A) and "type" what you want, see if there's an action and what shortcut (if any) it has.

For e.g.:

[image]

Get also familiar with "Bookmarks". (Control Tab, Double Shift are also good) Control-E (recent is nice) think all these you can "type" to search in them as well and narrow the results using fuzzy search (aka: type TM for "TimeManager" for example). You get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the Ctrl-Shift-A tip.  But I looked through several different wordings and I can't find anything that'll do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Let me get back to you :)

Comment: @RyanLundy seems like you found a middle-ground. For what is worth, I rarely (not to say *never*) use the Find In Path that way. I normally do CTRL-SHIFT-F and search from the floating window, but I see your point. Good luck with IntelliJ! :)